# Search tweets by site/url

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

I want  to use the twitter  stream api to get  tweets where a certain site occure in the "expanded_url" field, that is - find all tweets that links to any page on a specific site.

A search for "cnn.com" would for example find a tweet containing this:

```
"entities": {
          "url": {
            "urls": [
              {
                "expanded_url": "http://edition.cnn.com/2015/06/22/politics/opm-hack-18-milliion/index.html",...
```

The idea is to find full URI's for content on a  domain/site by searching for all expanded_url that contains a site domain (cnn.com in the example here)

I am currently finding theese tweets by using this search:

> https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&q=cnn.com

But this will obviously find more tweets than the ones that only has cnn.com in the expanded_url field.

Are there any way to specify a search query that can do a wildcard search in the expanded_url field ?

Comment: What results do you get if you search for the *full* URI?

Comment: I don't know the full uri so I cant search for it.  The idea is to find full URI's for content on a  domain/site by searching for all expanded_url that contains a site domain. I have now clarified my question.

Comment: Good question, it would be very useful, but I don't think you can do it, no.